# Ошибка DF-DFERH-01 при обновлении приложения на Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

У меня проблема - я выложил приложение на Google Play, оно стало доступно, но при обновлении выходит ошибка DF-DFERH-01. Эта ошибка происходит у многих пользователей моего приложения, поэтому найденное решение с очисткой кэша Google Play не подходит, проблема похоже не локальная. 
Так же я находил [такое решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265360/google-play-store-users-cant-download-app-because-of-error-df-dferh-01), где предлагают выставить политику конфиденциальности в настройках страницы приложения, но она у меня уже выставлена.

Как можно решить такую проблему? Спасибо за внимание!

P.S. Другие приложения обновляются без ошибок

Comment: https://fan-android.com/instructions/560-oshibka-pri-poluchenii-dannyh-s-servera-df-dferh-01.html
Второй вариант посмотрите

Comment: @RomanK. Спасибо, но это не сработало,  как и очистка кэша. + у меня три девайса с разными аккаунтами с такой проблемой, у всех трех другие приложения обновляются. Другие пользователи тоже подтверждают что не может обновиться только мое приложение.